# Replacing common elements in vectors in R

Tags: r

I have two named vectors. Some elements are common to both. I want to replace all the elements in first vector with their value in vector 2 if it is present in vector 2. 
Example:

```
Vector1:
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
0  0   0  0  0
Vector2:
A2 A5
3  5

Output Expected:
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
0   3  0  0  5
```

Comment: Please show some reproducible example and expected output.  Check with `%in%`

Comment: Added the details

Comment: Try `v1[names(v1) %in% names(v2)] <- v2`

Comment: @akrun If we can assume the names to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks it worked. If the question looks fine, can we remove the downvotes.

Comment: Because of these downvotes, my question asking priveleges have been removed. If you downvoted the question, can you please remove it. I have updated the question with proper explanation

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the comment is not generalized, only works when vector 2 is totally nested in vector 1 in terms of names (no element exists that appears in 2 and not in 1) and they are in the same order. A more generalized solution may be as such (I am changing the vector values and orders):

```
v1 <- c(A4 = 0, A2 = 0, A5 = 0, A1 = 3, A6 = 5)
v2 <- c(A5 = 3, A7 = 1, A2 = 4)

repvecs <- function(a = v1, b = v2) {
    commons <- names(a)[names(a) %in% names(b)]
    a[commons] <- b[commons]
    return(a)
}
```